# Intermittent blank result when fetching data from Oracle view in .NET core

Tags: c#, oracle, linq, entity-framework-core

## Context

I am trying to fetch data from an Oracle view using LINQ query in a .NET core application.

## Issue

- The data is **received correctly** most of the time, however, intermittently the data is just blank.

  - Eg: I might get 100 rows for the given search parameters. But, sometime for the same search parameters I get 0 rows.
- There are no errors (debugger does not go to the `catch`).
- The data starts coming after a couple of tries (re-execute the LINQ again)

### Additional Info.

- There are calls to SQL server using LINQ queries in the same application (different context). I have not faced similar issue.
- Using `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (2.1.4)`
- I am not aware of the Oracle version. I know only the View name & the columns.

## Code setup

### Entity Model

```
[Table("ORACLE_VIEW", Schema = "APPS")]
public class ORACLE_VIEW: BaseOracleEntity
{
    public string ORDER_NUMBER { get; set; }
    public string ORDER_DESC { get; set; }
    public string STATUS { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

```
public abstract class BaseOracleEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

### Repository

```
public interface IEntityORACLE_VIEW : IGenericOracleRepository <ORACLE_VIEW>
{
}
```

```
public class EntityORACLE_VIEW: GenericOracleRepository <ORACLE_VIEW>, IEntityORACLE_VIEW
{
    private AppDbOracleContext context;
    public EntityORACLE_VIEW(AppDbOracleContext _context) : base(_context)
    {
        this.context = _context;
    }
}
```

```
public class GenericOracleRepository<T> : IGenericOracleRepository<T> where T : BaseOracleEntity
{
    protected DbContext _entities;
    protected readonly DbSet<T> _dbset;
    public GenericOracleRepository(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        _entities = dbContext;
        _dbset = dbContext.Set<T>();
        _entities.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("alter session set NLS_LANGUAGE = 'AMERICAN'");
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<T> Table
    {
        get
        {
            return this._dbset;
        }
    }
    public virtual IQueryable<T> TableNoTracking
    {
        get
        {
            return this._dbset.AsNoTracking();
        }
    }
    //... has Add, Delete, Edit and few more methods, but not used in LINQ query
}
```

### Startup

In `ConfigureServices` method

```
services.AddDbContext<AppDbOracleContext>(options => options.UseOracle(Configuration.GetConnectionString("OracleConnString")));
...
...
services.AddScoped<IEntityORACLE_VIEW, EntityORACLE_VIEW>();
```

### DbContext

```
public class AppDbOracleContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbOracleContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbOracleContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }
    public DbSet<ORACLE_VIEW> ORACLE_VIEW{ get; set; }

}
```

### Function

```
public object GetOracleView(Model obj)
{
    try
    {
        var res = (from orcUser in _entityORACLE_VIEW.TableNoTracking
                  where (obj.WoStatus == null || !obj.WoStatus.Any() || obj.WoStatus.Contains(orcUser.STATUS))
                    && (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(obj.Search)
                    || (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(orcUser.ORDER_DESC) && orcUser.ORDER_DESC.ToUpper().Contains(obj.Search.ToUpper()))
                    || (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(orcUser.ORDER_NUMBER) && orcUser.ORDER_NUMBER.ToUpper().Contains(obj.Search.ToUpper()))
                    )
                   select new  ORACLE_VIEW_GridModel
                   {
                       Id = orcUser.ID,
                       Order = orcUser.ORDER_NUMBER,
                       Status = orcUser.STATUS,
                       Description = orcUser.ORDER_DESC
                   })
        .OrderByDescending(ord => ord.ORDER_NUMBER)
        .ToList();
        int count = res.Count();
        var result = res.Skip(obj.Skip).Take(obj.Take).ToList();
        return new APIResult
        {
            Result = result,
            Count = count
        };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new APIResult
        {
            ErrorDescription = ex.Message
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: EF Core 2 is ancient and no longer supported, the Oracle providers back then were pretty bad and using a low-level "repository" antipattern on top of a high-level Unit-of-Work like DbContext makes things a lot worse. It adds bugs especially in transactions but offers no benefits. ORMs like EF Core deal with *entities* not tables, trying to give the impression of working with in-memory objects instead of tables and rows. There's no `View` or `Table` in C#, there are classes

Comment: The codes exceptions too. Perhaps Oracle or EF Core threw an exception but the client code didn't notice because all it sees is an opaque `object` result. Or perhaps the unconventional queries resulted in no matches. `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` can't be translated to SQL, definitely not *effective* SQL that can use indexes, so EF Core would have to load the entire table to check the results. `orcUser.ORDER_NUMBER.ToUpper()` will emit `UPPER(ORDER_NUMBER) LIKE '%....%` which can't use any indexes. The answer is to use the correct collation and probably function-based indexes in the database

Comment: Check [How to do case-insensitive and accent-insensitive search in Oracle Database](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/post/how-to-do-case-insensitive-and-accent-insensitive-search-in-oracle-database). This explains the problems with attempting to just uppercase everything (including missed results), how to use collations instead and how to create case-insensitive indexes to speed things up. This would allow you to clean up the query considerably. It wouldn't solve the inefficient `LIKE '%....%'` clause though